# How to handle error message in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm automating an application using `Selenium` so what is happening is when the script runs and it hits the login button an error comes up in the top right which stops further execution. What I want is need a way by which i can capture this "error message" so that I would know the cause of the halt of the application execution.I'm attaching the image of error and also the code that I have tried but it didnt work.

[image: error message]

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='toast-container']/div/div]")
    static WebElement errorMessage;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(CommonBrowserSetup.driver, 15);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(errorMessage));
            String mess=errorMessage.getText();
            System.out.println(mess);
```

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: http://192.168.0.193:8000/#/login

Comment: Just share the html code for the error which you are getting.

Comment: <div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right" aria-live="polite" role="alert">
<div class="toast toast-error" style="opacity: 0.0831694;">
<button class="toast-close-button" type="button" role="button">×</button>
<div class="toast-message">Unknown error occured</div>

Comment: You your test case is:
If login failed , you just need to capture the text `Unknown error occured` and display it on console so that you can know the failure. Is it?

Comment: Yes right.That's all i want.

Comment: Read Post:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture `Unknown error occured`
Just try the following code and let me know if it works for you.
After the login button is clicked add the following:

```
WebElement Error =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Unknown error occured')]"));
            if(Error.isDisplayed()){
                String Errormessage = Error.getText();
                System.out.println(Errormessage);
            }
```

Comment: for handling error, put your code inside `try` and `catch block`. suppose think one scenario like by chance error is not occur, then element not found exception will showing. so for avoid that exception put your above code inside try and catch block.

Comment: InvalidSelectorException , the given selector (By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Unknown error occured')")); is either invalid or does not result in a weblement. This is what i m getting on using above code.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='toast-message']"));` Try this

Comment: @Johny : I required more html code. Please attach more html code in your question only.

Comment: @kishan In your xpath `]` was missing. please correct it.